# $T$ be a linear operator on an infinite dimensional complex vector space , then is it true that $T$ has a proper invariant subspace?

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a complex vector space of dimension greater than $1$ , then is it true that $T$ has an invariant subspace which is proper ? I can prove it if the complex vector space is finite dimensional , but what if it is infinite dimensional  ? Please help . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're asking about continuous linear operators in particular.  If that is the case, then the answer is [unknown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_subspace_problem).

Comment: No , I am asking for just linear operators ...

Comment: Then see the Wikipedia article under history. There exist linear operators with no invariant subspaces.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: this is incorrect. The Wikipedia article about the invariant subspace problem is about *closed* invariant subspaces of actions on topological vector spaces.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan that makes sense now

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Specifying a linear operator $T : V \to V$ induces a $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module structure on $V$, where $x$ acts by $T$, and proper invariant subspaces correspond to proper $\mathbb{C}[x]$-submodules. Every $v \in V$ generates a $\mathbb{C}[x]$-submodule $\mathbb{C}[x] v$, so either one of these is proper or $V$, as a $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module, is a quotient of $\mathbb{C}[x]$. $\mathbb{C}[x]$ itself has lots of proper submodules, such as $x \mathbb{C}[x]$, and any proper quotient of it is finite-dimensional.